# How to create a windows x86 VM in DevTest Lab?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-devtest-labs

I tried to create a windows x86 VM in Azure, I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image) to prepare a VHD and upload it to Azure. Then I created a VM by this image in DevTest Lab, but it failed. Failure information:

> "statusMessage":
>   "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The
>   resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"OSProvisioningTimedOut\",\"message\":\"OS
>   Provisioning for VM 'yaolin001' did not finish in the allotted time.
>   The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Please check
>   provisioning state later. Also, make sure the image has been properly
>   prepared (generalized).\r\n * Instructions for Windows:
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/
>   \r\n * Instructions for Linux:
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/
>   \"}]}}"

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: As it says in the error message, the VM might need more time to provision.

Comment: did you install the azure agent on the vm? this might be the cause of this

Comment: Is this still a blocker?

Comment: Sorry to reply late, I am not working on it recently, if it is still a problem, I will reply to you.

Comment: It is still a blocker, as I can't find a 32-bit agent, the The Windows VM Agent needs at least Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bits) to run.